# Why can't I answer this protected question even with my bonus network rep?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, protected-questions

I can't answer this question: [Is the Glass Half Full with water?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/3313/2674)

There is this message in place of the answer box:

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.
>
> Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?

When I look at my privileges in my profile, the privilidge "remove new user restrictions" is ticked:

[image: privilidges]

Why can't I answer the question?

I've refreshed a couple of times and left and come back to the question to make sure that I'm legitimately logged in, and I definitely am.

Comment: That's my question! I understand the bonus being excluded, but the protected message should state it's excluded.

Answer (score 4):

Question protection does not factor in the +100 reputation association bonus.

For reference, see [this discussion on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question); basically, questions are protected when users who are new to the site may not necessarily completely understand what constitutes a good answer. Frequently, we'll see upwards of six answers on hot questions that contain one sentence that is of considerably low quality, which is why this question has been protected.

While this may not be the type of answer you would have posted, such is the unfortunate restriction of protected questions.

However, I do agree that the message is poorly-worded and should better convey this point. [I've bountied the feature request on Meta.SE about this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174793/a-better-wording-for-protected-questions)

Comment: While I totally understand this thinking, perhaps it would be a good idea to remove the "Post more links, *answer protected questions*" next to the privilege explanation on the privileges page.

Comment: @Stacey Oooh, that's a good point that I don't think has been mentioned yet. I'll add that to the bounty message.